# How to build openjfx on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: compiling, gradle

I have been trying to build openjfx on Ubuntu 14.04 but i'm receiving error

```
gradle tasks
:buildSrc:clean
:buildSrc:generateGrammarSource
:buildSrc:compileJava
/home/nika/openjfx/rt/buildSrc/src/main/java/com/sun/scenario/effect/compiler/backend/sw/sse/SSEBackend.java:85: error: ')' expected
    Comparator<Variable> c = (v0, v1) -> v0.getName().compareTo(v1.getName());
                                ^
/home/nika/openjfx/rt/buildSrc/src/main/java/com/sun/scenario/effect/compiler/backend/sw/sse/SSEBackend.java:85: error: ';' expected
    Comparator<Variable> c = (v0, v1) -> v0.getName().compareTo(v1.getName());
                                    ^
2 errors
:buildSrc:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

 BUILD FAILED

 Total time: 5.334 secs
```

Anybody know how to build openjfx on ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: @user308564 sorry brother , actually my question was for OpenJFX.

Comment: JFX means javafx isn't it?

Comment: Yes, It is. But Oracle's Jdk8 with JavaFX is different from OpenJFX.

Comment: @user308564 :) Good to know , Also please change your name , it feels weird talking to user308564 :P

Comment: I think this name is better. We all are human no? Name is in my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , Download the latest version of Gradle. Gradle on Ubuntu's repo can't be used to build openjfx8. However the following link can be helpful to build Openjfx.

https://github.com/hgomez/obuildfactory/wiki/How-to-build-and-package-OpenJDK-8-with-OpenJFX-on-Linux

Thanks to H.Gomez for Obuildfacory     :) .....